# skipping Byte Order mark (BOM) when using Stream CopyTo

Tags: c#, file, byte-order-mark

I am trying to merge files into an output file and my individual files have the BOM on them, how can I get rid of it while using Stream.CopyTo method..

My code looks like this:

```
using (var output = File.Open(outputFile,FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write))
      {
         foreach (var inputFile in inputFiles)
         {
           using (var input = File.OpenRead(inputFile))
           {
              input.CopyTo(output);
           }
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following method..

```
using (var output = File.Open(outputFile,FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write))
      {
         foreach (var inputFile in inputFiles)
         {
           using (var input = File.OpenRead(inputFile))
           {
               input.Position = Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble().Length;  //The encoding might be any type.
              input.CopyTo(output);
           }
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use streams for copying text. Use StreamReader/StreamWriter instead:

```
        using (var output = File.AppendText(outputFile))
        {
            foreach (var inputFile in inputFiles)
            {
                using (var input = File.OpenText(inputFile))
                {
                    while (!input.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        output.WriteLine(input.ReadLine());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Any stream instance works at the byte-level, and it knows nothing about "character encoding" and "BOM".

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that for arbitrary files. The BOM are a few bytes which could be perfectly valid encodings. In the example below the code happens to write a file which has the same bytes as the text "ABC" encoded in UTF-16, little-endian, with a BOM, but that doesn't mean that the first two bytes represent a BOM (or even that the file represents "ABC").

```
public class StackOverflow_10594371
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create("a.bin"))
        {
            fs.WriteByte(0xFF);
            fs.WriteByte(0xFE);
            fs.WriteByte(0x41);
            fs.WriteByte(0x00);
            fs.WriteByte(0x42);
            fs.WriteByte(0x00);
            fs.WriteByte(0x43);
            fs.WriteByte(0x00);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText("a.bin"));
    }
}
```